# Blender Crashing within two minutes of opening even if left untouched after opening

Tags: windows, memory-management

I'm brand new to blender. I downloaded the newest version from online (2.79.2), checked to make sure I have good requirements for using the program (which I do), I start up the program and literally all I did the first time was move the default cube along the x,y,z axis and it crashed before the minute was up. I could hear the computer running harder for about thirty seconds before the crash.

The second time I turned on Task Manager to see if my CPU was peaking while using the program. It only spiked a little when turning on the program but moving the cube didn't cause any spikes. BUT even just turning it on and not touching anything within Blender at all the program still crashed.
Tried this many many times with the same results, tried an option recommended by other users to change from None under compute devices (system options) to CUDA and picked my card - made no difference. Tried running a python script that worked for someone else and that didn't work. Disabled the intel chipset that was recommended by another user so the computer would only be able to pick the Nvidia Graphics Card for use - didn't help.
Any ideas?
Not sure where I can look for crash logs for this?

SPECS
Windows 10 
Nvidia Geforce GT 525M
8GB RAM

Comment: Bugs (which this sounds like) are not covered in this section of stackexchange. Have you tried downloading/running an [older build](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/)? (Such as 2.79.)

Comment: I submitted this to the "report a bug" section of blender.org as well. Haven't tried an older version yet. I will when I get home tonight.

Comment: This smells to me like a hardware fault issue, or something deeply misconfigured on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I did test an older version and had the same problem. However...

Solution:
Couldn't find the crash files for blender so I checked the Eventviewer for Windows and saw a bunch of errors relating to my Wacom tablet. I uninstalled the Wacom tablet program, restarted and Blender has yet to crash again. :)